# Power of a diagonal matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, diagonalization

Let's say I have a linear transformation L: $\Bbb R [x] _{\le 2}$ to $\Bbb R [x] _{\le 2}$, a base B (the canonical for simplicity) and that I have the matrix $\Bbb[L]_{\ B}$ .
I know how to calculate the diagonal of L, but I have no idea on how to calculate this:

$\ L^n(1-x^2)$

Can somebody help, please?

Comment: I think that what you're asking is that you have a linear transformation $L$ and a basis $\mathcal{B}$ which diagonalizes $L$.  Then, the goal is to find the formula that is written above.  The $1-x^2$ doesn't make much sense, unless the underlying vector space are polynomials.

Comment: I edited it, I think it is more clear now :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Suppose that $[L]_B$ is a matrix which represents a linear transformation $L:R[x]_{\le 2}\rightarrow R[x]_{\le 2}$ with respect to the standard basis of polynomials.

Let $A$ be the change of basis matrix from the standard basis to the basis which the which the matrix of the linear transformation $L$ is a diagonal matrix $D$.

Then $[L]_B =A^{-1}DA$ and $[L^n]_B=A^{-1}D^nA$

If $$ D=\begin{bmatrix}
a&0&0\\
0&b&0\\
0&0&c\\
 \end{bmatrix}$$

then
$$D^n=\begin{bmatrix}
a^n&0&0\\
0&b^n&0\\
0&0&c^n\\
 \end{bmatrix}$$

Using this, you can find the coordinates of $L^n(1-x^2)$ with respect to the standard basis by multiplying the coordinates of $1-x^2$ in the standard basis by the matrix $A^{-1}D^nA$

Comment: Sorry, I originally answered this assuming that $L$ was diagonal with respect to the standard basis. The above argument won't work if it isn't so I'm going to update the answer to reflect this...

Comment: Ok, I'll wait for the update, thanks.

Comment: Updated it just now